# How remove trashed WooCommerce orders from wc_get_orders() result?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I like to use `wc_get_orders()` function to get WooCommerce orders in front end.

Here is my code snippet to get orders.

```
$args = array(
    'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    'return' => 'ids',
    );
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

var_dump($customer_orders);
```

The above code will return all orders of current users.

The issue is, the wc_get_orders return all orders including trashed orders. Is there any option to exclude trashed orders?

More details about this function are available in [this link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query).

Comment: Sorry. Previously, I got wrong output due to some error. Now I confirmed that the wc_get_orders() function will exclude trashed orders.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Wp_Query` instead it will give you the option to get data with status.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shop_order',
 'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future','private', 'inherit', 'trash')  
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

$orders = $my_query->posts;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($orders);
echo "</pre>";
```

it will display All of your order.

hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of WP_Query, WooCommerce suggest to use wc_get_orders() and WC_Order_Query etc.